# Assign random UUID on a key's first occurrence in a stream

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I'm looking for a solution on how to assign a random UUID to a key only on its first occurrence in a stream.

Example:

```
time key  value  assigned uuid
  |   1     A    fff17a1e-9943-11eb-a8b3-0242ac130003
  |   2     B    f01d2c42-9943-11eb-a8b3-0242ac130003
  |   3     C    f8f1e880-9943-11eb-a8b3-0242ac130003
  |   1     X    fff17a1e-9943-11eb-a8b3-0242ac130003 (same as above)
  v   1     Y    fff17a1e-9943-11eb-a8b3-0242ac130003 (same as above)
```

As you can see fff17a1e-9943-11eb-a8b3-0242ac130003 is assigned to key "1" on its first occurrence. This uuid is subsequently reused on its second and third occurrence. The order doesn't matter, though. There is no seed for the generated uuid either.

My idea was to use a leftJoin() with a `KStream` and a `KTable` with key/uuid mappings. If the right side of the leftJoin is null I have to create a new UUID and add it to the mapping table. However, I think this does not work when there are several new entries with the same key in a short period of time. I guess this will create several UUIDs for the same key.

Is there an easy solution for this or is this simply not possible with streaming?

Comment: When you say `only on its first occurrence in a stream` it will only make sense if you ensure that events come in order. The order in Kafka is guaranteed by offset https://stackoverflow.com/a/41552691/2096986.
And when you say `This uuid is subsequently reused on its second and third occurrence.` you will have to keep a stateful operation on it. It could be a time window of X seconds or it could be an unbounded aggregation.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether the order is guaranteed by offset or time. First something should  create a UUID for all future changes of the same key. Can you give me an example for windowing and/or unbounded aggregation? Isn't this prone to timing issues?

Answer (score 1):

You can aggregate the raw stream as ktable, in the processing, generate or reuse the uuid; then use the stream of ktable.

```
    final KStream<String, String> streamWithoutUUID = builder.stream("topic_name");
    KTable<String, String>  tableWithUUID = streamWithoutUUID.groupByKey().aggregate(
        () -> "",
        (k, v, t) -> {
            if (!t.startsWith("uuid:")) {
                return "uuid:" + "call your buildUUID function here" + ";value:" + v;
            } else {
                return t.split(";", 2)[0] + ";value:" + v;
            }
        },
        Materialized.<String, String, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("state_name")
        .withKeySerde(Serdes.String()).withValueSerde(Serdes.String()));
    final KStream<String, String> streamWithUUID = tableWithUUID.toStream();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a join in your use case because joins are to merge to different streams that arrive with equal IDs. You said that you receive just one stream of events. So, your use case is an aggregation over one stream.

What I understood of your question is that you receive events: `A`, `B`, `C`, ... Then you want to assign some ID. You say that the ID is random. So, this is very uncertain. If it is random how would you know that `A` -> `fff17a1e-9943-11eb-a8b3-0242ac130003` and `X` -> `fff17a1e-9943-11eb-a8b3-0242ac130003` (the same). I suppose that you might have a seed to generate this UUID. And then you create a key based also on this seed.

I suggest you start with this sample of [word count](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/master/kafka-streams-samples/kafka-streams-word-count). then on the first map:

```
.map((key, value) -> new KeyValue<>(value, value))
```

you replace it with your map function. Something like this:

```
.map((k, v) -> {
    if (v.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
        return new KeyValue<String, ValueWithUUID>("1", new ValueWithUUID(v));
    } else if (v.equalsIgnoreCase("B")) {
        return new KeyValue<String, ValueWithUUID>("2", new ValueWithUUID(v));
    } else {
        return new KeyValue<String, ValueWithUUID>("0", new ValueWithUUID(v));
    }
})
...
class ValueWithUUID {
    String value;
    String uuid;
    public ValueWithUUID(String value) {
        this.value = value;
        // generate your UUID based on the value. It is random, but as you show in your question it might have a seed.
        this.uuid = generateRandomUUIDWithSeed();
    }
    public String generateRandomUUIDWithSeed() {
        return "fff17a1e-9943-11eb-a8b3-0242ac130003";
}
}
```

Then you decide if you want to use a windowed aggregation, every 30 seconds for instance. Or a non-windowing aggregation that updates the results for every event that arrives. Here is [one nice example](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/master/kafka-streams-samples/kafka-streams-aggregate).

Comment: `generate your UUID based on the value. It is random, but as you show in your question it might have a seed`  Unfortunately, it does not have a seed. Actually, my problem boils down to the question how to create the same UUID for the same key WITHOUT a seed. Therefore, in my example `assigned uuid` is completely random on its first occurrence but always the same afterwards.